# Which data structure in C++ suits to implement webbrowser history?

Tags: c++, stl

In one of the interviews, I asked by one of the interviewers how to implement history of web browser but don't show duplicates and need to show in reverse order meaning from most recent till the 5th website visited.

I told we can use linked list. When user enters a website it will be checked against a list of nodes and if the site is already present in the list, we will remove it from the list and add it as head. If it is not in the list, it will be simply added as head of the list. But he told order of complexity is O(n*n) and he asked me are there any other data structures or combination of data structured we could use to make the order of complexity as O(n). I didn't get any clue at that time. Can any one please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: There's tons of structures. I'd go with a hashmap keyed by url, with linked list of addresses, and a simple double-linked list queue for the most-recent-visited data.

Comment: @MarcB : Mark, could you please explain a little bit more if possible?

Comment: If you don't need the ability to remove arbitrary items from the history *and* if you are allowed to limit the size of the history (it sounds like you were given a limit of five entries?), then a ring queue would probably give much better performance than a linked list -- you have one less level of indirection to each item, no indirection in order to traverse the list, but with the same O(1) append time.

Comment: I think he may be looking for a `std::stack` where if you wanna go back you just pull the last address off the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in constant time if you are using your linked list plus a hash table with pointers to the list items.

Comment: Yeah. But I didn't get clue on how to do this. What would be the hash function looks like.

Comment: Your list items are URLs – that is, strings – or can at least be identified by a URL, right? So any standard string hash function will do.

Comment: Thanks. But what the hash function will return. For example, assume that user enters "google.com", I will send "google.com" as key to hash function, then how hash function will return index?

Comment: You could (not recommended) add together all the characters in the string and then take it modulo the table size.  If you want a thorough discussion of good hash functions, you'll need to consult any textbook on algorithms and data structures.  A web-search on “string hash function” might also help.  If your major concern is how to do that in C++, the answer will very likely be: simply use [`std::hash<std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/hash) or even just [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: For a simple-enough to understand real-world example, have a look at the [`hash_string`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob;f=lib/hash.c;h=d312a2644e25622718de776aeea26403d62caf2b;hb=master#l392) function in the `hash` module in [Gnulib](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/).

Answer (score 1):

um... 
   With a linked list, Add URL to the start of the list (`O(1)`), continue throught list, deleting if found (`O(n)`)

Comment: Yeah. I think I got confused in the interview.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, Using a list and an unordered map would be your best bet. When visiting a new page, if the user has never visited it, add it to the end. if they have visited, recall the iterator using the hash map and remove it. The last step is to then add the url to the start of the list and give it a fresh new iterator in the map.

```
#include <list>
#include <unordered_map>
class browser
{
public:
    void visit (const std::string& page)
    {
        auto location = locations.find(page);
        if (location != locations.end())
        {       
            pages.erase(location->second);
        }
        pages.push_front(page);
        locations[page] = pages.begin();
    }

private:
    using Pages = std::list<std::string>;
    using Locations = std::unordered_map<std::string, Pages::iterator>;

    Pages pages;
    Locations locations;
};
```